# XMPPFramework - Which XMPPRoster function to use to send a friend request?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to implement an Instant Messaging App where users can chat as well as add other users to their roster and accept buddy requests. So, far I have been able to implement the chat and I am also able to receive and accept/reject friend requests.

For accepting/rejecting a subscription request, the code is as follows:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online / offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
    NSString *presencefromStr=[presence fromStr];

    if  ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"subscribe"]) {
        if(buttonIndex==1) { // For accept button
            [xmppRoster acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:[tmpPresence from] andAddToRoster:YES];
    }
    else { // For reject button
        [xmppRoster rejectPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:[tmpPresence from]];
    }
}
```

However, now I am stuck with the problem of not being able to send a friend request. Can anyone guide me on which function of XMPPRoster to use? I tried using the **subscribePresenceToUser** function, but, it didn't work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Also, can someone tell if the way I am going with this XMPPRoster subscription mechanism is right or is there a better way to handle the friend requests in XMPPFramework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys, I could solve it finally. Here's the code I came up with:

     `XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:self.addFriendField.text];
    [xmppRoster addUser:jid withNickname:nil];`
    
This code snippet sends the request to other users and adds them to their Roster.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by OP in comment:

```
XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:self.addFriendField.text];
[xmppRoster addUser:jid withNickname:nil];
```

This code snippet sends the request to other users and adds them to their Roster.

Comment: Hey there , I tried this But didn't worked. I declare `XMPPRoster` in viewController and also setup it in setupStream. But still not working. Can you please help me sorting this out

Answer (score 0):

You can see [XMPPRoster.h](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/e1c5d8d9821b9c9d3178fb291b0ff0f8abdf74a9/Extensions/Roster/XMPPRoster.h) to see all the functions available inside the roster extension.

For your answer you have three options:

```
/**
 * Adds the given user to the roster with an optional nickname 
 * and requests permission to receive presence information from them.
**/
- (void)addUser:(XMPPJID *)jid withNickname:(nullable NSString *)optionalName;

/**
 * Adds the given user to the roster with an optional nickname, 
 * adds the given user to groups
 * and requests permission to receive presence information from them.
**/
- (void)addUser:(XMPPJID *)jid withNickname:(nullable NSString *)optionalName groups:(nullable NSArray<NSString*> *)groups;

/**
 * Adds the given user to the roster with an optional nickname,
 * adds the given user to groups
 * and optionally requests permission to receive presence information from them.
**/
- (void)addUser:(XMPPJID *)jid withNickname:(nullable NSString *)optionalName groups:(nullable NSArray<NSString*> *)groups subscribeToPresence:(BOOL)subscribe;
```

And to accept the friend request : (add as friend, as Fan or Decline)

addToRoster flag = true : Friend

addToRoster flag = false : Fan

```
/**
 * Accepts the presence subscription request the given user.
 * 
 * If you also choose, you can add the user to your roster.
 * Doing so is similar to the traditional IM model.
**/
- (void)acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:(XMPPJID *)jid andAddToRoster:(BOOL)flag;

/**
 * Rejects the presence subscription request from the given user.
 * 
 * If you are already subscribed to the given user's presence,
 * rejecting they subscription request will not affect your subscription to their presence.
**/
- (void)rejectPresenceSubscriptionRequestFrom:(XMPPJID *)jid;
```